# while creating module getting error

Tags: drivers, python-2.7, django

used this command to create module - `python manage.py startapp todos`

getting this error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "manage.py", line 17, in 
>       "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
>   ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?

please tell me how to solve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but installation of `python-django` package may help:

```
sudo apt-get install python-django
```

Comment: wow super... its working

Answer (score 1):

It's a good idea to create django projects in isolated environments, called [virtualenvs](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/). To get one type:

`sudo apt install python-pip`

to get pip. Then:

```
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv env-name -p python
source env-name/bin/activate
```

You should be seeing that your prompt has `(env-name)` in it.

Now you can install django:

```
pip install django
```

If you have firther problems refer to [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/).

Comment: @karel didn't notice. Changed that to match proper pytthon version